# Ajax error: full address to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call the full address to the requested page here, but I am getting [object Object] for xhr. Is this not supposed to return the full address instead of a reference to [object Object] for xhr.

```
function isValid(frm){
 $("#courseinfo").hide();
 $("#frm").validate();
 var dropDownSelected = $("#frm :selected").val();
     if (dropDownSelected == "404")
        {
    var txt = ($(this).text());

    $.ajax({url:"404_error.json", 
        data:{coursename:txt}, 
        type:"GET", 
        dataType:"json",
        success:fnsuccess, 
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
          $("#infohere").text("Error: " + xhr + " - " + xhr.status + " - " + error);
          $("#courseinfo").show();
         }
        }); // end of ajax                                      
 } // end of if 404
```

Comment: you are requesting JSON and it is returning JSON

Comment: what @adrichman means is that you need to change the `dataType` to the data format you are expecting.

Comment: given that his URL is "404_error.json", it seems to be what he should be expecting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wanted a URL to be returned I needed to write out the URI or use something similar to JavaScript's document.documentURI. I had expected the URL to be in XHR for JSON, but that is not the case.